# Get selected value from comboboxes (cascading) mvvm

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, combobox

I have 3 cascading comboboxes on my view, 2 are bind to ObservableCollection and one (the first one) has its own items. I would like to get selected value of each to save it to the database. I was trying to do this with SelectedItem but what I get was string name of table.

Can you please give me some advice?

ViewModel:

```
Public Property First() As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Activities_First)
    Get
        Return _First
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Activities_First))
        _First = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Second() As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Activities_Second)
    Get
        Return _Second
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Activities_Second))
        _Second = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property SelectedFirst() As tbl_Activities_First
    Get
        Return _SelectedFirst
    End Get
    Set(value As tbl_Activities_First)
        _SelectedFirst = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedFirst")
        If Not IsNothing(_SelectedFirst) Then
            BlockActivity = _SelectedFirst.BlockAct
            _Second.Clear()
            _Second = Me.FillSecondActivity()
            SecondEnabled = True
        Else
            SecondEnabled = False
        End If
        RaisePropertyChanged("Second")
    End Set
End Property


Public Property NonProcessAct() As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Non_Process)
    Get
        Return _NonProcess
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of tbl_Non_Process))
        _NonProcess = value
    End Set
End Property
```

XAML:

```
                            <ComboBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Please select category..." FontFamily="HP Simplified Light" 
                                      Width="342" Height="27" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Background="{x:Null}"
                                      SelectedIndex="{Binding EmployeeViewM.ActivityType, Mode=OneWayToSource}" SelectedValuePath="TabIndex" Margin="88,20,84.4,355.4">
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="Process" TabIndex="1"/>
                                <ComboBoxItem Content="Non-Process" TabIndex="2"/>
                                <I:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <I:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <I:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EmployeeViewM.ExecuteFill, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </I:EventTrigger>
                                </I:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBox>

                            <ComboBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Please select activity..." Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                                      FontFamily="HP Simplified Light" Height="27" Width="342" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="88,52,84.4,323.4">
                                <ComboBox.Style>
                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroComboBox}">
                                        <Style.Triggers>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EmployeeViewM.ActivityType, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding EmployeeViewM.First }" />
                                                <Setter Property="SelectedItem" Value="{Binding EmployeeViewM.SelectedFirst}"/>
                                                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="FirstActivity"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EmployeeViewM.ActivityType, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="1">
                                                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding EmployeeViewM.NonProcessAct }"/>
                                                <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Activity"/>
                                            </DataTrigger>
                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                    </Style>
                                </ComboBox.Style>
                            </ComboBox>

                            <ComboBox Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Please select second activity... (optional)" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
                                      FontFamily="HP Simplified Light" Height="27" Width="342" Background="{x:Null}" ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeViewM.Second}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="SecondActivity" Margin="88,84,84.4,291.4" 
                                      IsEnabled="{Binding EmployeeViewM.SecondEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"/>
```

Comment: The only combo that is really bound to an `ObservableCollection` seems to be the last one... The second one has no `ItemsSource` or `Items` set at all, and the first one has its `Items` set explicitly in XAML as ComboBoxItems with a String-type Content.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've made amendments to my question. First on has its own items. But the second one has - Setter under DataTrigger.

Comment: And which `SelectedItem` doesn't work? Only the second combo, or the third one too?

Comment: Both combos (2 and 3) are populated with your entities (`tbl_Activities_First` and `tbl_Activities_Second` respectively). The combos' `SelectedItem` properties will return an object of that same type. What do you want them to return instead?

Comment: Okay, let's take FirstActivity combobox. What I get is System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.tbl_Activities_First_B743EAC46D5B2FA46E31B2B40865CFAC37FAAD4467A83C933547E5AAE1B5945F, instead of FirstActivity (Test1, Test2, Test3 - this is what I have in the table)

Comment: What you're seeing is the String representation of your entity (what you get when you make `.ToString()` to it). The combo `SelectedItem` is returning a `tbl_Activities_First` object and you're treating it like a String, so it gives you its String representation.

Comment: It seems like there's code you're not showing, since this code is working and fine (sorta)... Where are you getting that String from? What does `FillSecondActivity()` do, for instance? Or are the combos working fine and you're just getting those weird Strings when trying to save to database? Can you show us that code, which is where the problem seems to lie?

Comment: @almulo, THank you for your support. I've done that. FillSecondActivity() is an method. What was missing here - column name in the code. I was calling _selectedFirst instead _selectedFirst.FirstActivity. Now, I get selected item. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you found it :)